# How to rerun a program in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I have 2 controller for 2 fxml files. In one controller I have a `handleOpen` function which opens a file chooser and gives the path to a Class which I  have called model. Then on the other controller a function, `treeTableDraw` gets this path, after clicking on Draw Button and runs the program. I have Another Button to reset the program. It sets the result back to null, but when open another file to run, the program crashes, because the path is null. How can I reset the program and make it use the new path which is selected from open file chooser?

```
//Gets the path from model and runs the program
public void treeTableDraw(ActionEvent event) {

    new Controller(model.getText());
    drawTable();
    numberOfFunctions = dc.getFuncAll().size();
    numberOfOrganizations = dc.getSortedAssignedOrg().size();
    funcLabel.setText(numberOfFunctions + "");
    orgLabel.setText(numberOfOrganizations + "");
    btnDraw.setDisable(true);

}

/**
 * Clrears TreeTableView and sets back labels
 * 
 * @param event
 */
public void treeTableReset(ActionEvent event) {
    btnDraw.setDisable(false);
    model.setText(null);
    funcLabel.setText("0");
    orgLabel.setText("0");
    treeTable.getColumns().clear();

}
```

This is RootLayout class which has open file function:

```
@FXML
private void handleOpen() {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    // Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
            "3lgm2 files (*.z3lgm)", "*z3lgm");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    // Show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());

    if (file != null) {
        path = file.toString();

        model.setText(path);

    }

}
```

Here is the model class

```
public class Model {
private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

public StringProperty textProperty() {
    return text;
}

public final String getText() {
    return textProperty().get();
}

public final void setText(String text) {
    textProperty().set(text);
}

}
```

This is the main, where I combine two fxmls and set stage:

```
public class Main extends Application {
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
private Model model = new Model();


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("IT-Saturation");
    initRootLayout();
    showOverView();

}

private void showOverView() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/view/OverView.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new OverViewController(model));

        AnchorPane overView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(overView);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new RootLayoutController(model));

        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        // show scene containing the root layout
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // gives controller access to main
        RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * 
 * @return primaryStage
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {

    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void showMostComputerizedStatistics() {
    try {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class
                .getResource("view/BirthdayStatistics.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Birthday Statistics");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set the persons into the controller.
        MostComputerizedController controller = loader.getController();

        dialogStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What if you use: `File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());` does that make any difference?

Comment: Maybe `path = file.getAbsolutePath();` will do the trick, but it's hard to tell because i can't see where it is going wrong.

Comment: i can only run the same file again. when i choose a new file the program won't get initialized.

Comment: I thought when I do setText(null) the path will be reset too, but obviously it is not the case.

Comment: Have you tried to not set the setText to null and just leave it and when you open a new filechooser dialog it will set the text to something else anyway when a new file is chosen. Maybe add `chooser.setInitialDirectory("\\users\\yourname\\);` or something simular.

Comment: yes, it is the same thing! not working.

Comment: Then i don't know. Hopefully someone else will respond that does know what is going on. Probably it has something to do with the 2 controller and 2 FXML files, but i don't have much experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the path. I had to reset the data which got initialized at the the former run of program. So after setting path to null I just newed the instance of class which had reference to data.

...

```
public void treeTableReset(ActionEvent event) {
    btnDraw.setDisable(false);
    //model.setText(null);
    funcLabel.setText("0");
    orgLabel.setText("0");
    treeTable.getColumns().clear();
    dc = new DataConstructor();

}
```